# Simplex Noise - Summation

Tags: noise, perlin-noise, procedural-generation, simplex, simplex-noise

I have been reading [this article](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf) [as requested by Nathan Reed](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/60962/how-does-simplex-noise-work#comment107867_60962) on Programmers.StackExchange. After some reading I stumbled upon a paragraph I really don't get. Can anyone explain this paragraph to me in a more simple language? (English is not my native language) If you want to read the original you can find it under "`Moving from interpolation to summation`".

> Simplex noise instead uses a straight summation of contributions from
>   each corner, where the contribution is a multiplication of the
>   extrapolation of the gradient ramp and a radially symmetric
>   attenuation function. In signal processing terms, this is a signal
>   reconstruction kernel. The radial attenuation is carefully chosen so
>   that the influence from each corner reaches zero before crossing the
>   boundary to the next simplex. This means that points inside a simplex
>   will only be influenced by the contributions from the corners of that
>   particular simplex.

Answer (score 4):

I’ll need to step back a bit and define some notation, so apologies for not getting straight to that paragraph.

For both classical Perlin noise and simplex noise, to get the value at a point x, the steps are:

- Find the vertices x_1,...,x_k of the cell containing x, where the cell is a square or cube (etc) for Perlin noise, and a triangle or tetrahedron (etc) for simplex noise.
- For each vertex x_i, generate a random unit vector n_i, and compute
  grad(x_i,x) = (x-x_i) dot n_i
  This is the “gradient ramp” mentioned in the paragraph.
- Combine these together with some weights, so the output is

  w_1 * grad(x_1,x) + … + w_k * grad(x_k,x)

The paragraph describes how to generate the weights w_i. For Perlin noise, the weights linearly interpolate (ignoring smoothing), so they always add to 1. For simplex noise, we can see how w_i is computed in the code later in your link; it’s

```
w_i = max(0.6 - d_i^2, 0)^4,
```

where d_i = |x-x_i| is the distance from x to x_i. This is the “radially symmetric attenuation function”. It’s radially symmetric because it only depends on the distance, not the direction of x-x_i. Attenuation just means it decreases as d_i increases.

The second half of the paragraph says that when we cross a boundary between two simplices, and replace one of the neighbours, say x_1, with a different vertex x_1’, the coefficient w_1 should become 0, so that the values match up at the boundary. This ascii diagram may or may not clarify:

```
1--2
| /|
|/ |
3--1’
```

The noise value is

w_1 grad(x_1,x) + w_2 grad(x_2,x) + w_3 grad(x_3,x)

in the top left triangle and

w_1’ grad(x_1’,x) + w_2 grad(x_2,x) + w_3 grad(x_3,x)

in the bottom right triangle. For these to match, w_1 and w_1’ should be zero on the boundary.